# How to have a Service keep track of multiple clauses from other Services

Tags: angularjs

I want to have a service that returns true only when 3 or more async events from other services have completed successfully and any time one of them fails, have it be false.

Basically and "isReady" for the entire application.
For example, it would be true after login + fetch some user data + fetch some other user data.

How can I do that other then dispatching events from all involved services which are listened to in this service and doing something like `cond1 && cond2 && cond3` etc?

Thanks.

Comment: can wrap promises from all 3 in `$q.all(/* promise array*/).then...`  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `all` method of the `$q` service, wich takes an array of promises and convert it into one unique promise.

[Documentation for $q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)

In your case, you have 3 different services doing 3 async calls. So you need something like this in your controller :

```
$q.all([service1.data(), service2.data(), service3.getData()]).then(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
}, function (err) {
    $scope.data = "Something failed...";
});
```

For more details, [check this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/neKfCPhPe4IrFH3Duh8p?p=preview).

Comment: I did think about that, but I'm not sure which error callback would trigger if one of them failed.

Comment: @Francisc  same thing but with one being rejected  http://plnkr.co/edit/NSsMX79p0ZALro26rNpG?p=preview

Comment: Oups, missed your comment because of the oddly named `off-topic` banner above. I'll take a look at both of your links right now. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, that's brilliantly simple. Thank you, guys.